# Unable to perform join in the inner lists of a list of lists

Tags: python, list

I have a list of list in which the inner lists has members that are strings of single character separated by a comma. I am trying to define a function that would iterate over the inner list and perform a join function. 
I have a list such as `[['E', 'F', 'J', 'A',], ['S', 'D', 'G', 'K], ['A', 'S', 'R', 'J',], ['H', 'E', 'A', 'N']]`

My target list is ==> `[['EFJA'], ['SDGK'], ['ASRJ'], ['HEAN']]`
I used the following

```
def newlist(old_list):
    for i in old_list:
        sep = ('')
        newlist = sep.join(i)
        return newlist
```

By running the function I obtain a string which is the result of performing the join on only the first inner list in the list of list i.e. `'EFJA'`
But using the ide directly i obtain this

```
d = [['E', 'F', 'J', 'A',], ['S', 'D', 'G', 'K'], ['A', 'S', 'R', 'J',], ['H', 'E', 'A', 'N']]
sep = ('')
for i in d:
    new = sep.join(i)
    print(new)
```

**OUTPUT**

```
EFJA
SDGK
ASRJ
HEAN
```

The desired output is obtained. I would like to obtain same output with the function i defined.

Comment: `[[''.join(i)] for i in d]` using lc

Comment: In first function you immediately returns at the end of first iteration. So you gets only last string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should put all your individual results into another list and then only when you’re done, return the final list:

```
def newlist(old_list):
    new_list = []
    for i in old_list:
        sep = ''
        new_list.append(sep.join(i))
    return new_list
```

Or you can shorten this to:

```
def newlist(old_list):
    return [''.join(x) for x in old_list]
```

As you seem to want every string within its own single-element list (tbh. that does not make that much sense to me), you can just put the result of the join within extra brackets to create that extra list. So in the verbose function, you would do this:

```
new_list.append([sep.join(i)])
```

Or using the solution with the list comprehension, you would do

```
return [[''.join(x)] for x in old_list]
```

Comment: If I write `newlist` instead of `new_list` then is it technically wrong (when I am not calling recursively too) **?** I means my function name and local variable name are same

Comment: No, inside the function `newlist` is a local variable which won’t overwrite the global name that points to the function. So you won’t get in trouble using the same name, unless you want to reference the function yourself. But I would still recommend you to give it some other name, yet alone to not be confusing. In this case, you probably should give the function a better name (possibly including a verb like “make” or “get”).

Comment: Thanks Grijesh. It works well and like you suggested It doesn't make much sense creating an inner list of the Joined strings.